# Download large Images from server and showing in listview Items

Tags: android, image, android-volley

I used volley network library and networkimageview to display the listview. Images download from server all images are big sizes. i used gzipinputstream but gzip is not enough. i want to more effective way to download data. another problem is my heap sizes increases when i download the data and Images disk cache memory increased. Is there any effective way to implement download large data.

Comment: try Lazy loading example.Google with this key word, you will get tons of examples

Comment: Volley wasn't designed to handle big data. You should use another library.

Comment: any other library for download big data's? sorry for my poor english

Comment: I guess we'll never know